# Error term in asymptotic expansion of $(1+ax)^{-1/x}$ as $x\to\infty$

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

According to WA we have as $x\to\infty$
$$
(1+ax)^{-1/x}=1-\frac{\log ax}{x}+O(1/x^2).
$$
I am confused on how one obtains the error term. Here is what I tried
$$
(1+ax)^{-1/x}=\exp(-\tfrac{1}{x}\log(1+ax))=\exp(-\tfrac{1}{x}(\log ax+O(1/x))).
$$
Using the Taylor series for $e^x$ we have
$$
\exp(-\tfrac{1}{x}(\log ax+O(1/x)))=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}(-\tfrac{1}{x}(\log ax+O(1/x)))^k=1-\frac{\log ax}{x}+O(1/x^2)+O((-\tfrac{1}{x}(\log ax+O(1/x)))^2).
$$
So it would seem my issue is that I am not convinced the last term is $O(1/x^2)$.  Could someone please clarify this for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there when you wrote $(1+ax)^{-1/x}=\exp\left(-\frac1x\log(1+ax)\right)$. Since $x$ is very large, $\frac1x\log(1+ax)$ is very small because
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log(1+ax)}x=0
$$
Thus, using the Taylor approximation for $\exp$ at $0$,
$$
\exp\left(-\frac1x\log(1+ax)\right)=1-\frac1x\log(1+ax)+O\!\left(\left(\frac{\log(1+ax)}x\right)^2\right)
$$
We also have that
$$
\begin{align}
\log(1+ax)
&=\log(ax)+\log\left(\frac{1+ax}{ax}\right)\\
&=\log(ax)+\log\left(1+\frac1{ax}\right)\\
&=\log(ax)+O\!\left(\frac1{ax}\right)\\
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
(1+ax)^{-1/x}=1-\frac{\log(ax)}x+O\!\left(\left(\frac{\log(x)}{x}\right)^2\right)
$$
In fact, since $e^x=1+x+\frac12x^2+O\!\left(x^3\right)$, the error term should be about $\frac12\left(\frac{\log(x)}{x}\right)^2$.

Thus, it seems that WA's error term is a bit too small.

[image]

This shows that the error is about $\frac12\left(\frac{\log(x)}{x}\right)^2$.

Comment: I knew that $O(1/x^2)$ from WA seemed off!. Thank you.

Comment: Just out of curiosity : do you know why in WA or Mma it is always $O(x^n)$ ? By the way, nice solution. Cheers :-)

Comment: "$\textsf{SeriesData}[x,x_0,\{a_0,a_1,\dots\},n_\text{min},n_\text{max},den]$
represents a power series in the variable $x$ about the point $x_0$. The $a_i$ are the coefficients in the power series. The powers of $(x-x_0)$ that appear are $n_\text{min}/den,(n_\text{min}+1)/den,\dots,n_\text{max}/den$." Actually error term is  $O\!\left((x-x_0)^{n_\text{max}/den}\right)$ and the powers stop before $n_\text{max}/den$. I could be wrong, but I think it is the format of $\textsf{SeriesData}$ that is to blame.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$\ln(1+ax)=\ln(ax)+\ln(1+\frac{1}{ax})$$

$$=\ln(ax)+\frac{1}{ax}+o(\frac 1x)$$

$$\frac{-\ln(1+ax)}{x}=-\frac{\ln(ax)}{x}-\frac{1}{ax^2}+o(\frac{1}{x^2})$$

$$=-\frac{\ln(ax)}{x}+O(\frac{1}{x^2})$$

now, take the exponential.